# Regular Expresion

Tags: javascript

I need to get this (15 321,35) now I have this 15321.35
I have some mistake, and cant find, any ideas?

function money(cislo) {

```
var cifry = cislo.toString();    
var koma = /\./g, 
 probel = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g;

console.log(cifry.replace(koma, ',').replace(probel, '$1 ');
}
var cislo = 15321.35;
money(cislo);
```

Comment: This kind of question has been already answered - please read:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-string

Comment: Thank you, yes it's pretty similar:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some syntax errors. You were missing a closing bracket in your `console.log();`

I've also change the replace function to replace the `'.'` without regex as it isn't needed. It makes the code overly complex.

```
function money(cislo) {
  let cifry = cislo.toString();
  let probel = /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+([^\d]|$))/g;

  console.log(cifry.replace('.', ',').replace(probel, '$1 '));
}

var cislo = 15321.35;
money(cislo);
```

Comment: Thank you:) This code looks better and this missing ) , ohhhhhh:)

Comment: If this helped, mark the answer as correct, thanks!

Comment: One more question? what if I wanna add the $ at the end of the number? replace(probel, '$0$'), $0 is everything, and $ should add me ''dollar'' at the end!

Comment: If you're just adding the `$` symbol to your string you can just add it to your string: `console.log(cifry.replace('.', ',').replace(probel, '$1 ') + "$");`